# Integer solutions of $x^y-z^3=2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is it an open question to solve $x^y-z^3=2$ in integers (both positive, zero and negative)? If not, what kind of methods the solution requires?

Comment: Does $(x,y,z)=(3,1,1)$ count?

Comment: It is one of the solutions. But I was wondering if we have a proof that some set of triples gives all solutions.

Comment: "Solve" usually doesn't mean "find a solution." @BarryCipra

Comment: There seem to be several solutions, for example $(29,1,3)$, $(127,1,5)$, $(24391,1,29)$, $(250049,1,63)$, $(328511,1,69)$.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, there are infinitely many solutions of the form $(z^3+2,1,z)$. The question is, are there other solutions?

Comment: Never said it was clever. Those I listed have $x$ as a prime though, making them a little more interesting :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, in answer to your question to mrf, yes:  $(x,y,z)=(1,3,-1)$.

Comment: @BarryCipra I don't think solutions of the form $(1, y, -1)$ are any more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If $y$ is even, the only solutions to $-t^3 + u^2 = 2$ are $(-1,\pm 1)$

```
E_+00002: r = 1   t = 1   #III =  1
          E(Q) = <(-1, 1)>
          R =   0.7545769032
           2 integral points
            1. (-1, 1) = 1 * (-1, 1)
            2. (-1, -1) = -(-1, 1)
```

http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL+

Things do not change very much if you allow $-2,$ all you get is $27 - 25 = 2.$

```
E_-00002: r = 1   t = 1   #III =  1
          E(Q) = <(3, 5)>
          R =   1.3495768357
           2 integral points
            1. (3, 5) = 1 * (3, 5)
            2. (3, -5) = -(3, 5)
```

http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL-

Also, $y$ cannot be divisible by $3,$ as you can factor the difference of cubes and get a finite number of things to rule out. So, you have $y=5,7,11,13,\ldots$

My guess is that there is a book somewhere on Catalan's conjecture, now proved, with a chapter on changing the difference between powers from $\pm 1$ to $\pm 2, \pm 3,$ and a few other small numbers.

Whatever the exact contents, there is a book called Catalan's Conjecture by Rene Schoof, http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b16478355~S1

Comment: Instead of "$y$ cannot be even," don't you mean "If $y$ is even, then $x=\pm1$ and $z=-1$"?

Comment: @BarryCipra, I see, you think he is allowing all integers, not just positive. Alright.

Comment: @WillJagy I meant all integers, not just positive ones.